# What does "play the beard" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

This is a scene from the movie *Synchronicity*.

> Jim: Was I **playing the beard** tonight?
>
> Abby: Why do you ask?
>
> Jim: Well, either you came to the lab with Klaus or you got there through the wormhole.
>
> Abby: I did arrive with Klaus. But I'm leaving with you.

I am not sure what "playing the beard" means in this context, and it appears to be a total non-sequitur. It doesn't seem to be idiomatic. I can only think of it being sort of a reference to Jim being a facade/playing a role for Abby.

Comment: I don't see how it fits this dialog, but one meaning of *beard* is a person of the opposite sex who goes to public events as the date of a gay person, so that other people won't realize the gay person is gay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dialogue in this movie is plodding and uninspired.  It seems to me the writers heard this slang expression somewhere and misunderstood its meaning, but decided to include it anyway to try and add some life to the script.  From what little I watched, it doesn't work.

My best guess is it's supposed to mean that Jim thinks that Abby came to the restaurant as Klaus' date, and (for some reason) used Jim to try and make Klaus jealous.  Or something.

What a *beard* usually means is: Any person of the opposite sex taken to an event in an effort to give a homosexual person the appearance of being heterosexual.  This often is applied to celebrities who, for personal or professional reasons, want to keep their sexual orientation private.